# Effect of shape on memory allocation by tensorflow on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory

When I create a variable with shape `(L, N, N)` on a nvidia GPU with tensorflow, does the variable occupies a tiling of L square pieces where each piece is N x N?

For example, three square chunk of memories tiled together would be:

```
# --- #
| NxN |
# --- #
| NxN |
# --- #
| NxN |
# --- #
```

How would tensorflow allocate GPU memory for a variable with a shape of `(a, b, N, N)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory on the GPU is allocated as a 1-dimensional array of bytes, with alignment if possible. In your example, the tensor with shape `(L, N, N)` will be a 1-D array of size `8*L*N*N` bytes; the `(a, b, N, N)` case will be `8*a*b*N*N` bytes, assuming `float64` values.

You can find this out by reading the TensorFlow source code:

- [`gpu_cudamalloc_allocator.h`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3d44d4411e7fe6abcf6bdd2031cec8690b486c29/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_cudamalloc_allocator.h) declares the `GPUcudaMallocAllocator` class with `void* AllocateRaw(size_t alignment, size_t num_bytes)`, implemented in
- [`gpu_cudamalloc_allocator.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/7bd23b650b79e68662f834a0a5625897785b5c06/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_cudamalloc_allocator.cc).
- [`allocator.h`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.h) declares the `Allocator` class, parent of `GPUcudaMallocAllocator`, which declares `void* AllocateRaw(size_t alignment, size_t num_bytes)`.

Since these `AllocateRaw` functions take a single size, all TensorFlow memory is allocated in 1-D arrays under the hood. This is common in practice, since it's easy to map higher-order array representations onto a contiguous 1-D block of memory, and it maximizes throughput for transfers onto the device and back.

Comment: Thanks for digging into so many details. Would we do matrix multiplication faster if the two matrices are allocated as a square piece of memory on the GPU? For CPU I remember that matrix multiplication is faster if one of the matrix is transposed before the multiplication. Storing 2D matrix as 1D array mean strided memory access along either the row or column of a matrix.

Comment: Ok... all the multiplications probably happen concurrently on the GPU. So I guess strided access isn't that bad because all access actually happen concurrently.

Comment: The optimal algorithm for matrix multiplication on the GPU is not the same as the CPU algorithm. I believe the leader is *blocked outer product matrix multiplication* ([ref](https://www.public.asu.edu/~ashriva6/teaching/ARC/papers/Matrixmultiplicationgpu.pdf)). Use of the shared block reduces the impact of strided memory access, which only occurs on the first read.